# How can I add properties to the user object when creating a user with email&password?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am creating user using this function in React-Native:

```
const createnewuser = await auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(register_email, register_password)
```

As you can see I am only giving email and password as parameters. Where should I add other properties (such as `emailVerfied` and `displayName`) to the user object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set emailVerified - that's set for you after the email verification process finishes.

If you want to set other profile parameters, you will have to make a call to [updateProfile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile) as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Comment: ok so how am I suppose to know if the `emailVerified` is set to true or false in order for me to allow users to login or not based on their email verification?

Comment: Email verification happens after sign-in.  It's not a requirement to sign in.  You can use the flag to limit what they can do after signing in, but you can't use it to prevent them from signing in.

Comment: but after a user is created they automatically are signed in, so, what's the point of emailVerified after all?

Comment: If you really want to verify the user email. You need to send an email verification to the create account email. Just using the function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword.then((userCredential) => userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification())` After user verify by clicking on email, it'll automatically change the user register.

Comment: @ErickMaeda after register a user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` it will automatically log the user in. So, how can I actually prevent that?

Comment: As I said, you can't.  A user can always sign in with email and password credentials as long as they provide those credentials.  I think you're trying to use Firebase Auth in a way other than what was intended.  Your app needs to handle the case where the user account is created and signed in, but before the email address is verified.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok but what's the point of `emailVerified` then?

Comment: To know if the email verification process has completed successfully.

Comment: @DougStevenson what if I log out user right after they have been registered so I can prevent them accessing my app before they verify their emails. So when the email is verified then I read the auth object for `emailVerified` on Log In and see if its `true` or `false` .

Comment: if that meets you needs, then do that.

Comment: I think it does, well I thought this is a standard flow for most of the apps. To prevent a user create multiple accounts we use emails and expect them to verify them, otherwise whats the entire point of having Registrations then right?

Comment: Not all apps require a verified email address.  The email address is unique within the project and can't be used by two users.  It is effectively a unique user ID. You are free to handle the auth flow of your app as you wish.

Comment: Even if the user is logged in. You can check if the email is verified. So take an action only if the emailVerified is true. It depends on your application logic.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your clarification. You are right about that, however, lets say a malicious user wants to register with someone's else email, or create multiple accounts using other people's email (friends, family, etc) , that is what I am trying to prevent. Of course I cant prevent people creating new emails and register with the new one but at least the chances of that happening will reduce significantly.

Comment: @ErickMaeda thanks, I already figured this out. I will do it this way.